# Looking for a book: Humans spontaneously combust to another planet, their imperfections are the food for the aliens

Tags: story-identification, books

I’m looking for a book written in the 60s/70s…where the humans spontaneously combusting, and when the protagonist investigates, he finds out that they are actually being eaten, that’s is, their imperfections are the food of a particular alien species. I remember also that somehow while their imperfections are being eaten, they experience an orgasm? And then they come back as perfect Greek god people.
This also happens to the protagonist because somehow someone figures out how to be ‘eaten’ by this alien.
I remember the book cover had a drawing of these floating pool islands in the sky… Ring any bells?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Since you are new have a look at our [tour] and [help]. Also feel free to edit in any more details you can think of that might help our users answers your question, this reference is a good guide [How to ask a good story-id question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: _Fire Pattern_ by Bob Shaw has aliens causing humans to spontaneously combust and get swapped to another planet (Mercury), but the aliens weren't eating their imperfections - they swapped bodies with them. Also from 1984, so probably not your book.